# How do I unmap the keyboard shortcut for [ALT]+[\]?

Tags: 22.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

When I hit the keyboard shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, it opens some context menu in the top left of the window.

This shortcut is stepping on a vscode shortcut, so I want to remove it. But when I go to global shortcuts and search for <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, it says there is nothing mapped to that, even though there clearly is.

How do I unmap it?

Comment: "Alt+\" (question title) or "Alt+" (body of the question)? Which desktop environment? "Some context menu"? Where is "global shortcuts"? How can you search for "alt+" in the default Ubuntu desktop, or perhaps you are using a different desktop environment?

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard shortcut you're encountering is not managed directly by the global shortcuts settings, to fix that you can disable the keyboard shortcut in GNOME, run that command in a terminal `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "['disabled']"` and if you want to revert it `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "['<Alt>backslash']"`

Comment: How do you know this question is about Alt+grave if the title says "Alt+\" and the body "Alt+"? I think the question needs some clarification first, including information on desktop environment (in particular on how one can search for "Alt+" - I do not think that is possible on the default Ubuntu DE)

Comment: It was an example, I modified my answer to precise it

Comment: I am still not sure how you decide this question is about Alt+Grave, if the question itself refers to Alt+\ and in the text body, is not clear about what key is involved.

Comment: I modified my answer for clarity

Comment: Equally unclear to me. You mean Alt+space? On a standard US keyboard, there is no Alt+: "+" is shifted, so it would be Alt+Shift+"=". Anyway, you have an answer to your question already.